# Flutter: How to add multiple Sets of Markers to Google Maps

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I tried for hours now...

Does anyone have an idea how to make a Google Map with two different kind of Markers?

Some markers are blue and some are red. The user should be able to turn off only blue markers, so he sees only the red ones or the other way around.

I tried with multiple `Set<Marker>` but `markers:` only allows one Set. I also tried to give the different markers different booleans for visibility but this also didn't work.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [How can user add multiple marker on google maps flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58927260/how-can-user-add-multiple-marker-on-google-maps-flutter)

Comment: And after a quick google search, I can see lots of resources / guides. Have you checked them out? Example would be: https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/73/how-to-add-multiple-markers-on-google-map-flutter/

Comment: @Yrll I know how to add multiple markers. But I don't get how to add multiple markers, where there are two groups of them. Depending on with Group they should look different and have different onTap Functions.

Comment: Then please edit your question and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue so that the community could help you better.